# How to compare object with interface in Typescript to see if object has right variable type?

Tags: typescript

So I'm learning Typescript and I wanted to learn how to check that object has right value types.

Problem: I have body from API that looks like this:

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: "Jhonny",
   college: "Stanford",
   etc..
}
```

And now I've created interface:

```
export interface CheckData {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   college: string;
   etc..
}
```

And now what I want is to compare that object with this interface and display a message if something is missing or is in correct type, trying to achieve this:

validate.ts

```
import {CheckData} from '../interfaces'

export const validateData = (postData: object) => {

    //i want to achieve logic like this
    if(postData !== CheckData){
       console.log(`${whichParamIsntOkay} is not in a valid data type or it's missing`
    }
}
```

`postData` is passed into `validateData` from other file. So I want to compare these two, to check if all is there and if it's not to output which data in `postData` is missing or it's not in right format. Eg. if `postData` don't have `id` display `id is not in a valid data type or it's missing`. Same if `id` is passed as a string.

How to achieve this? Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm also using NodeJS + Typescript.

Comment: Typescript does not have runtime so it's impossible with just using the typescript's `interface`. But you can use the `io-ts` library.

Comment: @zerkms could you explain my how to use that library as solution to my problem? Thanks!

Comment: You would have to do it the same way you would in Javascript, since Typescript compiles to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Interface `CheckData` lays in different scope than all your values.

The safest way to check if value fits `CheckData` interface is to use [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
export interface CheckData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    college: string;
}

const data = {
    id: 123,
    name: "Jhonny",
    college: "Stanford",
};

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const requiredProps = ['id', 'name', 'college'] as const;

const isCheckData = (obj: unknown): obj is CheckData =>
    requiredProps.every((prop):prop is keyof CheckData => hasProperty(obj, prop));

const validateData = (postData: object) => {
    if (isCheckData(postData)) {
        const check = postData; // CheckData
    }

}
```

Please keep in mind that I checked only keys. You should probably check if values of `obj` are assignable to `CheckData`  to make it 100% safe.

**UPDATE**

```js
export interface CheckData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    college: string;
}

const data = {
    id: 123,
    name: "Jhonny",
    college: "Stanford",
};

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const requiredProps = ['id', 'name', 'college'] as const;

const missingKeys = (obj: unknown) =>
    requiredProps.filter((prop) => !hasProperty(obj, prop));

const result = (postData: object) => missingKeys(postData) // array of missing keys
```

Comment: Thank you on the answer! I just want to check couple of data, not all, so that is why I've created interface. I would also like to know how I would output the part with which variable is missing/not in correct type? I mean, I really don't know how to extract name of that variable that is causing the error.

Comment: please provide an example with error. It is not clear for me what output do U expect

Comment: You can see it in example with part of `console.log` there I'm expecting to get what variable is missing or has incorrect data type.

Comment: I made an update. `missingKey` will return array of missing keys. If it returns empty array, it means that your object has all required keys